# Any row-oriented analogy to selecting dataframe column by name?

Tags: r, dataframe

A column of a dataframe can be extracted by `name` (same as `colname`) but not a `rowname`.  Example dataframe:

```
> dbar
   aa    bb    cc
r1  1   one 1e+01
r2  2   two 1e+01
r3  3 three 1e+01
r4  4  four 1e+01
r5  5  five 1e+01

Rgames> dbar$aa
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Rgames> dbar$r2 #doesn't work
NULL
 # have to to something like
Rgames> subset(dbar,rownames(dbar) =='r3') #or dbar[rownames(dbar=='r3'),] 
   aa    bb    cc
r3  3 three 1e+01
```

I can see that allowing `df$somename` to search row names would mean requiring the `data.frame` functions to verify that all column and row names as a single set be unique.  So, am I asking too much :-) or should I just stick with the methodologies I used above?

Comment: Shouldn't `dbar["r3",]` work as well?

Comment: `dbar$r2` is just dbar[["r2"]]. I think 'data.table' might you use `dbar <- data.table(dbar);setkey(dbar, rownames(dbar)); dbar["r2"]`.

Comment: @rmk yep; that works, and is even stated (indirectly) on `?'['` , where it says you can reference by any `dimname` element.  Go ahead and post as an answer and I'll check it off.  Thank you!

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, looks like @ intra got there first and probably needs the rep more than I do at this point. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a somewhat open-ended question but if you are subsetting by row and would like to use the rowname, @rmk is right.

Example data frame:

```
    DF <- data.frame(A = rep(c(1,2), 5), B = rep(10, 10))
    row.names(DF) <- letters[1:10]
```

To which `DF["a",]` returns:

```
  A  B
a 1 10
```

Or you can use the row index `DF[1,]`.